# How can I know what apps are on my phone but not in my iTunes library?

Tags: itunes, ios, ios-appstore

I constantly get the following warning dialog when doing a backup of my device to my computer through iTunes.

[image: There are apps on your device which are not in your iTunes library. Would you like to back up these apps from your iPad?]

Clicking yes does not prevent this from happening in the future. Clicking no does nothing to tell me what apps I'll be "losing" if I were to restore.

**How can I find out which apps are only on the iPad and not on the computer?** To make this even more frustrating, I originally selected to delete all apps from the device that did not exist in my library in the past during a normal sync operation; on top of that, automatic downloads for apps is enabled in iTunes settings and any app I purchase should be automatically added to my iTunes library.

Answer (score 1):

This does not tell you which items are causing the issue, but it resolves the issue by transferring whatever is needed.  In iTunes, go to the File menu, devices, transfer purchases from ....